# How do you rotate PNG files using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have tried ffmpeg.exe -loglevel error -i \"$Image_Folder$file\" -filter:v \"transpose=1\" \"$Output_Folder$file\

but this crashes ffmpeg.exe

so maybe it only works for videos?

Comment: Show full log. For ffmpeg, an image is basically a video with one frame.

Answer (score 2):

This is how you rotate PNG files by 90 degrees clockwise. Using different versions  of ffmpeg you will find that some versions causes ffmpeg to crash and other versions to work fine.

```
ffmpeg.exe -loglevel error -i "a.png" -filter:v "transpose=1" "a.png"
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the version of ffmpeg. The latest version ffmpeg-20171114-91a565e-win64-static causes it to crash.

Using an older version of ffmpeg, there is no problem. For example:
ffmpeg-20170312-58f0bbc-win64-static
is OK

ffmpeg can definitely rotate PNG images by 90 degrees clockwise.

Comment: How can the issue be duplicated?

Comment: The issue is duplicated by using the 2 different versions of ffmpeg I wrote in my answer.

Comment: I should have asked, "what is the actual command being used so we can attempt to duplicate this issue?". Some time has passed–are you still experiencing the issue with a recent version?

Answer (score 0):

It might be too late. But if you can use `convert` to rotate the images.

To rotate 90 degrees counter-clock wise.

```
for photo in *.jpg ; do convert $photo -rotate -90 $photo ; done
```

Other Alternative is using `mogrify`

```
mogrify -rotate 90 *.jpg
```